# MySql FULLTEXT returning 0 results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a mysql Table with 25k records, MyIsam.
I was trying to run a full text search query, sometimes it will work sometimes not.

```
select article_id from news_article  where match(article_name,article_content) against(' (h.h h.hs) ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  order by article_date DESC
```

This is the query. I have set fulltext search key for article_name and article content. "ft_min_word_len" of my db is "3".

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this?

```
      against('h.h h.hs' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

if its two values then use this

```
    where article_name IN ('h.h' , 'h.hs')
    AND article_content in ('h.h' , 'h.hs')
```

Comment: its not 2 values, its like h.h or h.hs.
its not about the values, whenever a '.' comes, it will results 0 value :(